# What is the meaning of "Hotstepper" in Ini Kamoze's song?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In the song [Here comes the Hotstepper](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w0N4twV28Mw), sang by Ini Kamoze, is repeated the word "Hotstepper". I have been looking for the meaning of this specific word, but I don't seem to find the exact one in the context.

Most of the times the definition I have found for the word is:

> Used to define a person who is very skilled or adept at an activity.

But I also found several times the following definition:

> Used in Jamaica to describe a criminal on the run.

Which would fit more, as it is a Jamaican song and the lyrics seem to be closer to this meaning:

> Here comes the hotstepper, murderer
>
> I'm the lyrical gangster, murderer
>
> Pick up the crew in-a de area, murderer
>
> Still love you like that, murderer

Can I have any confirm on which meaning is the right one for this song?

Comment: "The Hotstepper" is Kamoze's nickname. It's a Jamaican term for a man on the run from the law. http://www.songfacts.com/detail.php?id=294

Comment: You should make this an answer.

Comment: http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=hotstepper definition 2 matches the comment from @JOSH See also rap genius: http://genius.com/Ini-kamoze-here-comes-the-hotstepper-lyrics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [comments](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/364597/what-is-the-meaning-of-hotstepper-in-ini-kamozes-song#comment849656_364597):

> "The Hotstepper" is Kamoze's nickname. It's a Jamaican term for a man on the run from the law. http://www.songfacts.com/detail.php?id=294
>   - Josh Dec 21 '16 at 13:08

Answer (score 1):

In some other countries it means

> SOMEBODY THAT ALWAYS HAVE AWESOME FUNKY BRAND NEW SHOES OR BOOTS
>
> HOTSTEPPER = THE MEANING FOR THE SHOES/BOOTS ETC.

Comment: Welcome to ELU, please don't answer in all caps. Instead, try using a quote block using the *>* sign.